# Regular expression given to grep

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to extract from a huge file looking like this :

```
.....
G:  Quantity 000001, removing 4 binary files
A: some stuff
.....
G: some other stuff
G: some infos
.....
G:  Quantity 000002, removing 1 binary files
....
A: some data
....
G:  Quantity 000003, removing 41 binary files
.....
```

all the lines "G:  Quantity ??????, removing * binary files".

I'm writing this pattern with the bash syntax as it is the one I am mostly familiar with, but grep doesn't interpret my question marks and the asterisk as bash does. What is the corresponding grep syntax ?

The following syntax works :

```
grep "G:" filename | grep Quantity | grep removing
```

but it doesn't use any regex.

Comment: `cat grep.txt | grep -e ^G.*binary\ files$` something like that?

Comment: By "bash syntax" you probably mean "globbing pattern" which is NOT a regexp despite some similarities in purpose. google `regexp tutorial` and take it.

Answer (score 2):

In regex, the way to match any character is to use `.`.

If you want to match exactly N times any character, say `.{N}`. If you want to match at least one, say `.+`. Being this case where you want to match digits, it may be best to say `[0-9]` instead of a too generic `.`:

```
grep -E 'G:  Quantity [0-9]{6}, removing [0-9]+ binary files' file
```

This command returns:

```
G:  Quantity 000001, removing 4 binary files
G:  Quantity 000002, removing 1 binary files
G:  Quantity 000003, removing 41 binary files
```